# replace bullet point in <li> with image specified in respective post

Tags: html, css, hugo, blogdown

I have an html list element that renders blogposts as a list.

```
<ul class="posts">
{{ range .Data.Pages -}}
  <li>
    <span class="postlist_container">
      <a href="{{ .Permalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a> 
    <time class="pull-right post-list" datetime="{{ .Date.Format "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z0700" }}">{{ .Date.Format "Mon, Jan 2, 2006" }}</time> </span>
  </li>
{{- end }}
</ul>
```

The blogposts are written in markdown (well Rmarkdown) and I specify a source image that should appear in the list.

```
---
thumbnail: "/post/source/image_tn.jpg"
---
```

I managed to get the image rendered alongside the title of the post with adding an  tag inside the list.

```
<img src="{{ with .Params.thumbnail }}{{ . }}{{ end }}">
```

This is not ideal since there is a bullet point, then title, date and image. What I would like is that the image replaces the bullet point.

I have read about using CSS for this, but the examples always use an absolute path to one image, e.g.

```
.posts {
  list-style-image: url("source/image.jpeg");
}
```

Is there a way to refer to the image from the Param.thumbnail inside the markdown file?

This didn't work:

```
.posts {
  list-style-image: url("{{ with .Params.thumbnail }}{{ . }}{{ end }}");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your style sheet is not parsed, the path should be plain written , or  include this rule inside your document in between <style> tags so the path will be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your CSS style sheet use the markdown, you need to include it inside the HTML templates.

insert **once** inside your template the rule(s) you want to update on the fly (best is to insert inside `<head>`, but anywhere else will work

```
<style>
.posts {
  list-style-image: url("{{ with .Params.thumbnail }}{{ . }}{{ end }}");
}
</style>
```

instead

```
<img src="{{ with .Params.thumbnail }}{{ . }}{{ end }}">
```

---

Best is to read about the template tutorial from blogdown

> https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/templates.html#a-minimal-example
>
> The partials/ directory is the place to put the HTML fragments to be reused by other templates via the partial function. We have four partial templates under this directory:
>
> header.html main defines the `<head>` tag and the navigation menu in the `<nav>` tag.

if you read further, you can see that the  `{{ partial "head_custom.html" . }}` is the file (head_custom.html) where you might insert

```
<style>
.posts {
  list-style-image: url("{{ with .Params.thumbnail }}{{ . }}{{ end }}");
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out that option. Its good to know that syntaxe `{{}}` doesn't work in css. One thing to report is that it only worked when I put the syle-tag inside `<li><\li>`. However, I then realized that replacing the bullet point with the image is somewhat difficult to align properly, I therefore went with the option to remove the bullet point and display the elements in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `list-style-image`, why don't you use one of the pseudo elements? Like so!

```
li{
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

li::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: url("{{ with .Params.thumbnail }}{{ . }}{{ end }}") no-repeat center center;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Additionally, you can specify the `background-size`

Comment: syntaxe `{{}}` only works in the template, CSS file are not part of the template, so the path will not be rewritten on the fly. that you use background or list-style-image ...

Comment: Then the OP can set it in an `img` tag and place it before the content of `<li>`

Comment: Thanks for your help. It didn't work. Is there a way to specify this in the template?

Comment: Extending my above comment, `<li><img src={{ with .Params.thumbnail }}{{ . }}{{ end }} /> content here </li>`

Comment: Yes, I got to that solution before, but the problem still remains in that the bullet point stays and the image doesn't really replace the bullet point.

Comment: The image won't automatically replace the bullet point. Set `li { list-style: none; }`

Comment: This is an acceptable workaround. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Just a follow up: inside the li element, I have the image and an <a > element. How can I display those in one line? I would have expected that I could wrap them around a <span > and they would be displayed in one line. But that doesn;t work.. Any idea?

Comment: Set `li` to `display: flex`. It's immediate children, the `img` and `a` tags will become flex items and get in one line. Then you can play with the `justify-content` property to decide their spacing from each other

Comment: Works great. Thanks for your help @Nimsrules